# Python Arcade library doesn't draw sprites (blank window)

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, arcade

I'm trying to draw a simple .png file (a car) using the arcade library. However, after following the tutorial, I can't get the image of the car to show on the screen. I'm using Pycharm Community 2019.2 on windows 10 x64 and python 3.6 (anaconda virtual environment).

I've even downloaded the example from: http://arcade.academy/examples/platform_tutorial/index.html and unzipped the directory, preserving the file/folder structure. When I run the provided file "02_draw_sprites" the result is a blank window with no sprites or anything.

The file "02_draw_sprites" can be seen here: 
http://arcade.academy/examples/platform_tutorial/index.html#step-2-add-sprites

There were no errors or warnings during the execution of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a new virtual environment with python 3.7.5 (conda create -n myvenv37 python=3.7) and then pip install arcade, solved the issue.